# About START_STICKY in Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

About using [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) in Android Service.

official document says:

> if this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the
>   started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system
>   will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state,
>   it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after
>   creating the new service instance;

This is understandable, so when an started service's process is killed due to lack of memory, the OS will automatically try to start the service again later.

My question is, if my code starts the service `startService(...)`, and later stop it(e.g. I have a "STOP" button on my app's UI, when press it, I call `stopService(...)`), will system later start the service again? Or will the service instance be cleared from memory completely without later being created by system? (No service binding for this scenario)

Comment: Using stopSelf() the service does not restart even if it is sticky. So no system will not start the service later on its own...

Comment: same for stopService(Intent) ?

Comment: yes same for `stopService(intent)` .. it doesn't get started later..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`START_STICKY-` tells the system to create a fresh copy of the service, when sufficient memory is available, after it recovers from low memory. Here you will lose the results that might have computed before.

And answer for your query is the service only recreate if it's killed by the OS in any circumstances when working with `START_STICKY`. if we were terminating the service why android need to reproduce it again.if your using `stopSelf()` the service does not recreate even it is sticky.

Comment: so if I have instance variables in MyService class, their values are set during service is running, once the service is killed by OS & start again, those instance variables' value will be lost, right?

Comment: obviously it will be lost for restarting in previous state u can follow up START_REDELIVER_INTENT ..

Answer (score 0):

I have had that `stopService()` button in my app during testing. Once you stop it using the command, it will not start again until you call `startService()`.

Answer (score 0):

Android kill the process from time to time. However Sticky service is recreated automatically by android system. Somebody told, Sticky services are destroyed and are recreated after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

START_STICKY is the operation mode of the started services, depending on the value they return from on StartCommand() method.START_STICKY is used for services that create the copy of service but it won`t store any result of services which is performed before.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Logs.d(TAG, "# Service - onStartCommand() starts here");

// If service returns START_STICKY, android restarts service automatically after forced close.
// At this time, onStartCommand() method in service must handle null intent.
return Service.START_STICKY;
```

}